# Changing Style of SVG Images

Tags: svg

I am looking for a way to change the colour of the lines of an SVG using an onclick function that adds and removes classes. I manage to change the background colour but not the colour of the image itself.  I want the red colour to change to white when I click on the function.

This is the SVG

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="16" viewBox="0 0 21 16" fill="none">
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0_114904_5525)">
      <path d="M19.6528 15.2547C19.4182 15.2551 19.1896 15.1803 19.0007 15.0412L10.7487 8.958L2.49663 15.0412C2.38078 15.1267 2.24919 15.1887 2.10939 15.2234C1.96959 15.2582 1.82431 15.2651 1.68184 15.2437C1.53937 15.2223 1.40251 15.1732 1.27906 15.099C1.15562 15.0247 1.04801 14.927 0.96238 14.8112C0.876751 14.6954 0.814779 14.5639 0.780002 14.4243C0.745226 14.2846 0.738325 14.1394 0.759696 13.997C0.802855 13.7095 0.958545 13.4509 1.19252 13.2781L10.0966 6.70761C10.2853 6.56802 10.5139 6.49268 10.7487 6.49268C10.9835 6.49268 11.212 6.56802 11.4007 6.70761L20.3048 13.2781C20.4908 13.415 20.6286 13.6071 20.6988 13.827C20.7689 14.0469 20.7678 14.2833 20.6955 14.5025C20.6232 14.7216 20.4834 14.9124 20.2962 15.0475C20.1089 15.1826 19.8837 15.2551 19.6528 15.2547Z" fill="#FF3D00"/>
      <path d="M19.6528 9.50568C19.4182 9.50609 19.1896 9.43124 19.0007 9.29214L10.7487 3.20898L2.49663 9.29214C2.26266 9.46495 1.96957 9.5378 1.68184 9.49468C1.39412 9.45155 1.13532 9.29597 0.962385 9.06218C0.789449 8.82838 0.716541 8.53551 0.7597 8.24799C0.802859 7.96048 0.95855 7.70187 1.19252 7.52906L10.0966 0.958588C10.2853 0.818997 10.5139 0.743652 10.7487 0.743652C10.9835 0.743652 11.212 0.818997 11.4007 0.958588L20.3048 7.52906C20.4908 7.66598 20.6286 7.85809 20.6988 8.07797C20.769 8.29785 20.7678 8.53426 20.6955 8.75344C20.6232 8.97262 20.4834 9.16338 20.2962 9.29847C20.1089 9.43356 19.8837 9.50608 19.6528 9.50568Z" fill="#FF3D00"/>
  </g>
  <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip0_114904_5525">
          <rect width="20" height="14.5098" fill="white" transform="translate(0.748535 0.745117)"/>
      </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

See details of the problem

Comment: You didn't add the SVG -- please do that

Comment: BTW. you can remove the clip-path as it doesn't clip any thing

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any classes in your example, but if you want to alter the `fill` attribute for each `<path>`, you can try the following:

```js
const colors = ['#FF3D00', '#DDDDDD'];

document.querySelector('svg > g')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const group = e.target.closest('g');
    if (!group.hasAttribute('clip-path')) {
      return;
    }
    const currPath = group.querySelector('path');
    const currColor = currPath.getAttribute('fill');
    const currIndex = colors.indexOf(currColor);
    const nextIndex = currIndex !== -1
      ? (currIndex + 1) % colors.length
      : 0;
    for (let path of group.querySelectorAll('path')) {
      path.setAttribute('fill', colors[nextIndex]);
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

svg > g {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="16" viewBox="0 0 21 16" fill="none">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip0_114904_5525">
      <rect width="20" height="14.5098" fill="white" transform="translate(0.748535 0.745117)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0_114904_5525)">
    <path d="M19.6528 15.2547C19.4182 15.2551 19.1896 15.1803 19.0007 15.0412L10.7487 8.958L2.49663 15.0412C2.38078 15.1267 2.24919 15.1887 2.10939 15.2234C1.96959 15.2582 1.82431 15.2651 1.68184 15.2437C1.53937 15.2223 1.40251 15.1732 1.27906 15.099C1.15562 15.0247 1.04801 14.927 0.96238 14.8112C0.876751 14.6954 0.814779 14.5639 0.780002 14.4243C0.745226 14.2846 0.738325 14.1394 0.759696 13.997C0.802855 13.7095 0.958545 13.4509 1.19252 13.2781L10.0966 6.70761C10.2853 6.56802 10.5139 6.49268 10.7487 6.49268C10.9835 6.49268 11.212 6.56802 11.4007 6.70761L20.3048 13.2781C20.4908 13.415 20.6286 13.6071 20.6988 13.827C20.7689 14.0469 20.7678 14.2833 20.6955 14.5025C20.6232 14.7216 20.4834 14.9124 20.2962 15.0475C20.1089 15.1826 19.8837 15.2551 19.6528 15.2547Z" fill="#FF3D00"/>
    <path d="M19.6528 9.50568C19.4182 9.50609 19.1896 9.43124 19.0007 9.29214L10.7487 3.20898L2.49663 9.29214C2.26266 9.46495 1.96957 9.5378 1.68184 9.49468C1.39412 9.45155 1.13532 9.29597 0.962385 9.06218C0.789449 8.82838 0.716541 8.53551 0.7597 8.24799C0.802859 7.96048 0.95855 7.70187 1.19252 7.52906L10.0966 0.958588C10.2853 0.818997 10.5139 0.743652 10.7487 0.743652C10.9835 0.743652 11.212 0.818997 11.4007 0.958588L20.3048 7.52906C20.4908 7.66598 20.6286 7.85809 20.6988 8.07797C20.769 8.29785 20.7678 8.53426 20.6955 8.75344C20.6232 8.97262 20.4834 9.16338 20.2962 9.29847C20.1089 9.43356 19.8837 9.50608 19.6528 9.50568Z" fill="#FF3D00"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

**Note:** You can place the `fill` attribute on the group instead of each `path`.

### Using classes

If you want to toggle a class, you could try:

```js
const colors = ['#FF3D00', '#DDDDDD'];

document.querySelector('svg > g')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const group = e.target.closest('g');
    if (!group.hasAttribute('clip-path')) {
      return;
    }
    group.classList.toggle('chevron-active');
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

svg > g {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="16" viewBox="0 0 21 16" fill="none">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip0_114904_5525">
      <rect width="20" height="14.5098" fill="white" transform="translate(0.748535 0.745117)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <style>
    .chevron {
      fill: #DDDDDD;
    }
    .chevron-active {
      fill: #FF3D00;
    }
  </style>
  <g class="chevron chevron-active" clip-path="url(#clip0_114904_5525)">
    <path d="M19.6528 15.2547C19.4182 15.2551 19.1896 15.1803 19.0007 15.0412L10.7487 8.958L2.49663 15.0412C2.38078 15.1267 2.24919 15.1887 2.10939 15.2234C1.96959 15.2582 1.82431 15.2651 1.68184 15.2437C1.53937 15.2223 1.40251 15.1732 1.27906 15.099C1.15562 15.0247 1.04801 14.927 0.96238 14.8112C0.876751 14.6954 0.814779 14.5639 0.780002 14.4243C0.745226 14.2846 0.738325 14.1394 0.759696 13.997C0.802855 13.7095 0.958545 13.4509 1.19252 13.2781L10.0966 6.70761C10.2853 6.56802 10.5139 6.49268 10.7487 6.49268C10.9835 6.49268 11.212 6.56802 11.4007 6.70761L20.3048 13.2781C20.4908 13.415 20.6286 13.6071 20.6988 13.827C20.7689 14.0469 20.7678 14.2833 20.6955 14.5025C20.6232 14.7216 20.4834 14.9124 20.2962 15.0475C20.1089 15.1826 19.8837 15.2551 19.6528 15.2547Z"/>
    <path d="M19.6528 9.50568C19.4182 9.50609 19.1896 9.43124 19.0007 9.29214L10.7487 3.20898L2.49663 9.29214C2.26266 9.46495 1.96957 9.5378 1.68184 9.49468C1.39412 9.45155 1.13532 9.29597 0.962385 9.06218C0.789449 8.82838 0.716541 8.53551 0.7597 8.24799C0.802859 7.96048 0.95855 7.70187 1.19252 7.52906L10.0966 0.958588C10.2853 0.818997 10.5139 0.743652 10.7487 0.743652C10.9835 0.743652 11.212 0.818997 11.4007 0.958588L20.3048 7.52906C20.4908 7.66598 20.6286 7.85809 20.6988 8.07797C20.769 8.29785 20.7678 8.53426 20.6955 8.75344C20.6232 8.97262 20.4834 9.16338 20.2962 9.29847C20.1089 9.43356 19.8837 9.50608 19.6528 9.50568Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```